# hosting of my website using php (symfony2) and neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have some questions in hosting of websites that use graph database **Neo4j**.

I have started in development of a website with relational database, but I have found some difficulties in certain points in database design, then I decided to migrate to graph database Neo4j.

I searched on Internet about how to host a website using **Neo4j**, but I didn't found an article that talk about this point and about estimated price for a small website.

I only found the clouds hosting, and I didn't find web hosting like godaddy, hostgator, ovh .... etc.

My website is developed by PHP (symfony2)

THANK YOU for helping me please....
Do I can make my website using Neo4j with a reasonable price ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The costs mostly depend on your graph size, the more ram you have the better. 
If your graph can fit in memory you'll get better performances.

If you intend to have not so much users, you can host your neo4j instance at vultr for e.g., however for high-availability and professional production environment, AWS likes infrastructures are required and are expensive.

On the other hand, I do not think the type of programming language does matter here, I'm also a symfony2 dev and the production configurations of neo4j I did remains the same for any other programming language.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question please ... Do I can install Neo4j (Edition Community) in a VPS Hosting ? Do I use version Community for my websites with any price ?

Comment: Yes you can. Now depending of your VPS configuration don't forget that the RAM will be shared for Neo, your app and the system.